# How do I run the same javascript with incrementing variable names

Tags: javascript, html, optimization

I have the following code, I know it's super inefficient, though I don't know how to make it simpler. Is there a way that button1 could just be changed to buttonX and everything could just be written once?

Apologies if this has been asked before. I have tried searching but it is quite a complicated thing to describe and I haven't found anything relevant.

```
var button1 = document.getElementById('toggle1');
var button2 = document.getElementById('toggle2');
var button3 = document.getElementById('toggle3');
var button4 = document.getElementById('toggle4');
var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
var div2 = document.getElementById('div2');
var div3 = document.getElementById('div3');
var div4 = document.getElementById('div4');

button1.onclick = function() {
        div1.style.display = 'block';
        div2.style.display = 'none';
        div3.style.display = 'none';
        div4.style.display = 'none';
};

button2.onclick = function() {
        div1.style.display = 'none';
        div2.style.display = 'block';
        div3.style.display = 'none';
        div4.style.display = 'none';
};

button3.onclick = function() {
        div1.style.display = 'none';
        div2.style.display = 'none';
        div3.style.display = 'block';
        div4.style.display = 'none';
};

button4.onclick = function() {
        div1.style.display = 'none';
        div2.style.display = 'none';
        div3.style.display = 'none';
        div4.style.display = 'block';
};
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML too? The answer to your question is yes. You should write 1 function that servers as the click handler for all buttons. That way you only need to write that repeating code once.

Comment: What you're wanting is how to create functions. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function https://medium.com/@zfrisch/writing-functions-in-javascript-de839053e9a8

Comment: Put your code suggestions into answers please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try with this - I have taken your code as example since you did not post HTML

The advantage of these two examples is that when you need to add a button and a div, the code does not change at all.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("[id^toggle]");
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].onclick = function() {
    const divs = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=div]"); 
    for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
      divs[i].style.display = divs[i].id == "div" + this.id.replace("toggle", "") ? "block" : "none";
    }
  }
}
```

Instead of ID selector and replace, you can use classes and data-attr

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".toggleButton"); 
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].onclick = function() {
    const divs = document.querySelectorAll(".toggleDiv");
    const showId = this.getAttribute("data-toggle");
    for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
      divs[i].style.display = divs[i].id == showId ? "block" : "none";
    }
  }
}
```

assuming `<button data-toggle="div1" class="toggleButton" type="button">Div1</button>`

Comment: Thank you, good idea about the data-attr and classes. Nice and efficient with pure JS.

Answer (score 0):

Consider placing everything into an array so you can do things by index.

```js
var buttons = [];
var divs = [];

for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  buttons[i] = document.getElementById('toggle'+(i+1));
  divs[i] = document.getElementById('div'+(i+1));

  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', doClick(i));
}

function doClick(index) {
  return function() {
    for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      divs[i].style.display = i === index ? 'block' : 'none';
    }
  };
}


doClick(0)();
```

```html
<div id="div1">One</div>
<div id="div2">Two</div>
<div id="div3">Three</div>
<div id="div4">Four</div>
<button id="toggle1">1</button>
<button id="toggle2">2</button>
<button id="toggle3">3</button>
<button id="toggle4">4</button>
```

In this code I am getting all four buttons and divs in a loop and setting up the event listeners for each button.

The function `doClick` is a curried function that uses a closure to set the `index` of the button that is being clicked on so we know which one we want to show and then we hide all of the others.

Comment: That is not very generic

Comment: define what you mean by `generic`. This code will work just fine in any condition with minor changes. What do you see as a problem?

Comment: For one you will have to change 4 to 5  TWICE if you add a new button. Instead use the existing HTMLElement arrays

Answer (score -1):

You can use javascript objects of course!

```
// let's match keys (1, 2, 3, 4) to buttons
var buttons = {
  1: document.getElementById('toggle1'),
  2: document.getElementById('toggle2'),
  3: document.getElementById('toggle3'),
  4: document.getElementById('toggle4')
}
// let's match keys (1, 2, 3, 4) to divs
var divs = {
  1: document.getElementById('div1'),
  2: document.getElementById('div2'),
  3: document.getElementById('div3'),
  4: document.getElementById('div4')
}

// this function will hide all divs except the once given as a param
function hideAllBut(index) {
  // go through each div
  for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    // if i is equal to the param, display the div
    if (i === index) {
      divs[i].style.display = 'block'; // accessing the divs object which has key i
    } else {
      // else hide it
      divs[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}

// now for each button, we call the function to hide all expect the one we want
buttons[1].onclick = function () {
  hideAllBut(1);
};

buttons[2].onclick = function () {
  hideAllBut(2);
};

buttons[3].onclick = function () {
  hideAllBut(3);
};

buttons[4].onclick = function () {
  hideAllBut(4);
};
```

Keeping that in mind, we can make the code even more dynamic

```
var buttons = {};
var divs = {};
// how many elements we have (here 4)
var totalElements = 4;
// assign buttons and divs values dynamically, while adding the onclick
for (var i = 1; i <= totalElements; i++) {
  buttons[i] = document.getElementById('toggle' + i); // i.e. if i=1, 'toggle'+i = 'toggle1'
  divs[i] = document.getElementById('div' + i);
  buttons[i].onclick = function () {
    hideAllBut(i);
  };
}

// this function does the same as how we wrote it perviously but with a different format
function hideAllBut(index) {
  for (var i = 1; i <= totalElements; i++) {
    // we use the ternary operator
    divs[i].style.display = (i === index) ? 'block' : 'none';
  }
}
```

Read the documentation of the javascript object because you're gonna use it a lot and will help you do stuff dynamically. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Ternary operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: That is so not generic. Why would he have to add a new entry to your object for every new button and div?

Comment: Again I will have to remember to change 4 to 5 in totalElements. Why not just count the elements that are on the page?

Comment: Isn't it what the question asked? `Is there a way that button1 could just be changed to buttonX and everything could just be written once?`

Comment: Add a button and a div and you will have to change the number. I prefer to give a solution that works always instead of just giving the OP what he asks.

Comment: But what it they don't button 5 to have this onclick? They asked for a solution to avoid having to write 1-4 manually, not for every button. But I may have misinterpreted what the actual purpose was.

Comment: Set a class and loop over the array of html elements with that class, then you do not care how many there are

Comment: It was an example of how it can be parametrized. Since there was no html code posted, I don't know if buttons > 4 have to be affected.

Answer (score -1):

With [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) you could do the following:

```js
$('.toggleButton').on('click', function() {
  var toggleDivId = '#toggleDiv' + $(this).attr('id').replace('toggleButton', '');
  $('.toggleDiv').css('display', 'none');
  $(toggleDivId).css('display', 'block');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="toggleButton1" class="toggleButton">Button 1</button>
<button id="toggleButton2" class="toggleButton">Button 2</button>
<button id="toggleButton3" class="toggleButton">Button 3</button>
<button id="toggleButton4" class="toggleButton">Button 4</button>
<div id="toggleDiv1" class="toggleDiv">Div 1</div>
<div id="toggleDiv2" class="toggleDiv">Div 2</div>
<div id="toggleDiv3" class="toggleDiv">Div 3</div>
<div id="toggleDiv4" class="toggleDiv">Div 4</div>
```

Comment: The question was not tagged with jQuery so a jQuery request does not make sense.

Comment: Just an alternative approach so it makes sense. Right tool for the right job.

Comment: Also please use .toggle(boolean) instead of .css

Comment: @mplungjan: I could do that but since i don't know the initial state of the divs (OP didn't post the HTML) I really can't.

Comment: You could if you ran the code onload and set the button or div to active :) or look to see if the button clicked had the same index as the div

Comment: @mplungjan: I agree. But all that assumes certain conditions which the OP doesn't provide.

Answer (score -2):

Here's an example using jQuery, that helps to avoid having to declare all the vars for each button first.

I also added a 'reset' button so you can get all the divs back. I'm not sure if this is what you wanted but to me this seems like the kind of thing jQuery is especially helpful for, so here is an example:

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
      $('.boxdiv').css({"display":"none"});
  switch ($(this).attr('id')) {
    case "1":
    case "2":
    case "3":
    case "4":
      $(`#div${$(this).attr('id')}`).css({"display":"block"});
      break;
    case "reset":
      $('.boxdiv').css({"display":"block"});
      break;
  }    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="float:left">
<button class="button" id="1">B1</button>
<button class="button" id="2">B2</button>
<button class="button" id="3">B3</button>
<button class="button" id="4">B4</button>
<button class="button" id="reset">Reset</button>
</div>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="boxdiv" id="div1" style="background-color:red;width:60px;height:60px;float:left;">  
</div>
<div class="boxdiv" id="div2"style="background-color:yellow;width:60px;height:60px;float:left;">
</div>
<div class="boxdiv" id="div3"style="background-color:blue;width:60px;height:60px;float:left;"> 
</div>
<div class="boxdiv" id="div4"style="background-color:green;width:60px;height:60px;float:left;">
</div>
```